# Crop UIImagePicker and output to CollectionView cell

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode5, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a camera button that takes a square picture that then fills a CollectionViewController cell. Right now, I'm having a little trouble cropping the picture and outputting it to the cell. In the lines of code commented "Crop the image to a square: I'm getting an error saying that "image" is an undeclared identifier. How do I crop the image and set it to a cell?

```
- (IBAction)cameraButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)]) {
        UIAlertView *cameraAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:@"There is no camera on this device which really defeats the purpose of this game. We suggest you get an iDevice with a camera." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cameraAlertView show];
    }else{
        UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        if (ipc.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            //Create camera overlay
            CGRect f = ipc.view.bounds;
            f.size.height -= ipc.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
            CGFloat barHeight = (f.size.height - f.size.width) / 2;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size);
            [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5] set];
            UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, 0, f.size.width, barHeight), kCGBlendModeNormal);
            UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, f.size.height - barHeight, f.size.width, barHeight), kCGBlendModeNormal);
            UIImage *overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            UIImageView *overlayIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:f];
            overlayIV.image = overlayImage;
            [ipc.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayIV];
        }

        ipc.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];

        //Crop the image to a square
        CGSize imageSize = image.size;
        CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
        CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
        if (width != height) {
            CGFloat newDimension = MIN(width, height);
            CGFloat widthOffset = (width - newDimension) / 2;
            CGFloat heightOffset = (height - newDimension) / 2;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newDimension, newDimension), NO, 0.);
            [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-widthOffset, -heightOffset)
                     blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy
                         alpha:1.];
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark ImagePicker Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.imageView.image = image;
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your "Crop" coded below this line:

`UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];` in 
`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

You will need to update your dataSource with the newly cropped image.  You can then either call `reloadData` or `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` on your UICollectionView to have it reflect the newly added image.  I would side with calling the latter method as it will be more efficient than reloading the entire collection with `reloadData` (when there are lots of images in the collection).

`UICollectionView` reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/insertItemsAtIndexPaths%3a).

Comment: That helps the cropping issue, but what about setting the image to a CollectionView cell?

Comment: I revised my answer, hope it helps.